# Passing variables (locals) into a partial when rendering a partial from Deface

Tags: deface

I have a [deface](https://github.com/spree/deface) declaration, that adds a partial to every page just above `</body>`.

```
Deface::Override.new(
  :virtual_path => 'spree/layouts/spree_application',
  :name => 'add_piwik_tracking_tag_to_layout',
  :insert_bottom => "[data-hook='body']",
  :partial => 'spree/piwik')
```

The partial needs some variables. An example is a local or helper method:

```
_paq.push(['setSiteId', <%= piwik_site_id %>]);
```

or an instance variable:

```
_paq.push(['setSiteId', <%= @piwik_site_id %>]);
```

or entirely without variables:

```
_paq.push(['setSiteId', <%= Spree::Config.preferred_piwik_id %>]);
```

Is there any way to pass them along from the `Deface::Override.new()`?

I am trying to avoid three potentially bad patterns, especially since this `piwik_site_id` is one of many variables being passed in:

- Opening the application_helper from within my gem and insert a helper-method.
- Opening the `ApplicationController` and set a `@piwik_site_id` there. Setting this on every controller, for every action and each template.

I'd prefer to not have to pollute the controllers of the application that have this gem available.

Comment: Did you figure this out?